# Create a HashMap with a fixed Key corresponding to a HashSet. point of departure

Tags: java, hashmap, hashset, wikipedia

My aim is to create a hashmap with a String as the key, and the entry values as a HashSet of Strings.

---

*OUTPUT*

This is what the output looks like now:

```
Hudson+(surname)=[Q2720681], Hudson,+Quebec=[Q141445], Hudson+(given+name)=[Q5928530], Hudson,+Colorado=[Q2272323], Hudson,+Illinois=[Q2672022], Hudson,+Indiana=[Q2710584], Hudson,+Ontario=[Q5928505], Hudson,+Buenos+Aires+Province=[Q10298710], Hudson,+Florida=[Q768903]]
```

According to my idea, it should look like this:

```
[Hudson+(surname)=[Q2720681,Q141445,Q5928530,Q2272323,Q2672022]]
```

---

The purpose is to store a particular name in Wikidata and then all of the Q values associated with it's disambiguation, so for example:

[This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bush) is the page for "Bush".

I want Bush to be the Key, and then for all of the different points of departure, all of the different ways that `Bush` could be associated with a terminal page of Wikidata, I want to store the corresponding "Q value", or unique alpha-numeric identifier.

What I'm actually doing is trying to scrape the different names, values, from the wikipedia disambiguation and then look up the unique alpha-numeric identifier associated with that value in wikidata.

For example, with `Bush` we have:

```
George H. W. Bush 
George W. Bush
Jeb Bush
Bush family
Bush (surname)
```

*Accordingly the Q values are:*

[George H. W. Bush](https://www.wikidata.org/w/index.php?title=Q23505&site=en&page=George+H.+W.+Bush+&submit=Search) (Q23505)

[George W. Bush](https://www.wikidata.org/w/index.php?title=Q207&site=en&page=George+W.+Bush&submit=Search) (Q207)

[Jeb Bush](https://www.wikidata.org/w/index.php?title=Q221997&site=en&page=Jeb+Bush&submit=Search) (Q221997)

[Bush family](https://www.wikidata.org/w/index.php?title=Q2743830&site=en&page=Bush+family&submit=Search) (Q2743830)

[Bush](https://www.wikidata.org/w/index.php?title=Q1484464&site=en&page=Bush+%28surname%29&submit=Search) (Q1484464)

*My idea is that the data structure should be construed in the following way*

**Key:**`Bush`
**Entry Set:** `Q23505, Q207, Q221997, Q2743830, Q1484464`

But the code I have now doesn't do that.

It creates a seperate entry for each name and Q value. i.e.

**Key:**`Jeb Bush`
**Entry Set:** `Q221997`

**Key:**`George W. Bush`
**Entry Set:** `Q207`

and so on.

The full code in all it's glory can be seen on [my github page](https://github.com/h1395010/database_builder/tree/master/src/main/java/Q), but I'll summarize it below also.

This is what I'm using to add values to my data strucuture:

```
// add Q values to their arrayList in the hash map at the index of the appropriate entity
public static HashSet<String> put_to_hash(String key, String value) 
{
    if (!q_valMap.containsKey(key)) 
    {
        return q_valMap.put(key, new HashSet<String>() );
    }
    HashSet<String> list = q_valMap.get(key);
    list.add(value);
    return q_valMap.put(key, list);
}
```

This is how I fetch the content:

```
    while ((line_by_line = wiki_data_pagecontent.readLine()) != null) 
    {
        // if we can determine it's a disambig page we need to send it off to get all 
        // the possible senses in which it can be used.
        Pattern disambig_pattern = Pattern.compile("<div class=\"wikibase-entitytermsview-heading-description \">Wikipedia disambiguation page</div>");
        Matcher disambig_indicator = disambig_pattern.matcher(line_by_line);
        if (disambig_indicator.matches()) 
        {
            //off to get the different usages
            Wikipedia_Disambig_Fetcher.all_possibilities( variable_entity );
        }
        else
        {
            //get the Q value off the page by matching
            Pattern q_page_pattern = Pattern.compile("<!-- wikibase-toolbar --><span class=\"wikibase-toolbar-container\"><span class=\"wikibase-toolbar-item " +
                    "wikibase-toolbar \">\\[<span class=\"wikibase-toolbar-item wikibase-toolbar-button wikibase-toolbar-button-edit\"><a " +
                    "href=\"/wiki/Special:SetSiteLink/(.*?)\">edit</a></span>\\]</span></span>");

            Matcher match_Q_component = q_page_pattern.matcher(line_by_line);
            if ( match_Q_component.matches() ) 
            {
                String Q = match_Q_component.group(1);

                // 'Q' should be appended to an array, since each entity can hold multiple
                // Q values on that basis of disambig
                put_to_hash( variable_entity, Q );
            }
        }

    }
```

and this is how I deal with a disambiguation page:

```
public static void all_possibilities( String variable_entity ) throws Exception
{
    System.out.println("this is a disambig page");
    //if it's a disambig page we know we can go right to the wikipedia


    //get it's normal wiki disambig page
    Document docx = Jsoup.connect( "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/" + variable_entity ).get();



        //this can handle the less structured ones. 
        Elements linx = docx.select( "p:contains(" + variable_entity + ") ~ ul a:eq(0)" );

        for (Element linq : linx) 
        {
            System.out.println(linq.text());
            String linq_nospace = linq.text().replace(' ', '+');
            Wikidata_Q_Reader.getQ( linq_nospace );

        }

}
```

I was thinking maybe I could pass the `Key` value around, but I really don't know. I'm kind of stuck. Maybe someone can see how I can implement this functionality.

Comment: Maybe you want to use a MultiMap of the google guava library.

Comment: yeah, i mean, i've used that before, i think the issue is with how data is being added, not the data structure itself, isn't it? 

how would using multimap help?

Comment: Can you be more specific about what isn't working? Your basic data structure seems sound. Are you getting errors or some other failures?

Comment: no no, it's just they it's not adding all Q values under the "point of departure" for the disambiguation, it's adding each Q value uniquely for the name that its associated with. it's not a bug, it's a design problem. so for instance, the term `Bush` should store the values for every related term, not, as it is now, that each related term has their own entry, do you know what i mean?

Comment: Where do you actually add the Q-value to the hash set? In the `put_to_hash(String, String)`, if the key is not contained in the map, you `return q_valMap.put(key, new HashSet<String>());`. I don't see the Q-value being added to the `new HashSet<String>()`

Comment: What about using a debugger and figuring out? According to the github code, you're using a text file to feed the thing, how do you expect the link "Bush" > "Q221997" to be made, I didn't see any code for that.

Comment: @RC. yes thats a good idea

Comment: BTW, the GitHub version of your code is mixing tabs and spaces, and looks like your editor is using 4-space tabs, so the indentation is wonky when viewed online or an editor with different tab settings.

Comment: @AndrewJanke hmm, thats strange, i know they always look weird on github, i'm using eclipse. i think that new function you wrote fixed a problem i didn't even know i had, which is definetly good, but actually i was originally trying to solve a different problem, i just posted the output to the top of this question, i think that should make the question, maybe, more clear

Comment: Okay. A couple things: a) What's your input? It looks like you need to figure out a way to get from "Hudson, Quebec" to just "Hudson" and the other things you need as a key. What are you starting from? b) Would be easier to debug if the input `NYTimesCorpus/2005/01/02/test/people.txt` file was on GitHub too. Just go ahead and stick it in the repo. c) This is sounding like a broad design or code review question and not a specific problem. May be off topic for SO and better on Programmers or elsewhere.

Comment: @AndrewJanke [here](https://github.com/h1395010/database_builder/blob/master/people.txt)'s the `people.txt` file, i think it's sort of a design problem but not in its entirety

Comment: Okay. The main problem is that you're not tracking the single-word key used to get to disambiguated pages. You need to pass that in to `Wikidata_Q_Reader.q()`. In the base call from `Runner`, `key` and `variable_entity` will be the same, but in the loop inside the disambiguation page fetcher, it'll pass the same `key` to each call it does for the links to various named pages it found.

Comment: @AndrewJanke yes! ok. great. i had notions of that, but I was clutching at straws, thank you for putting it into words. so i should just be passing that original `variable_entity` around the whole time, and that becomes the key isn't it? but I'm a little bit confused about how to make sure the different disambiguation entities stay assocaited with it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75999/discussion-between-andrew-janke-and-s-matthew-english).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not clear from your question what isn't working, or if you're seeing actual errors. But, while your basic data structure idea (`HashMap` of `String` to `Set<String>`) is sound, there's a bug in the "add" function.

```
public static HashSet<String> put_to_hash(String key, String value) 
{
    if (!q_valMap.containsKey(key)) 
    {
        return q_valMap.put(key, new HashSet<String>() );
    }
    HashSet<String> list = q_valMap.get(key);
    list.add(value);
    return q_valMap.put(key, list);
}
```

In the case where a key is seen for the first time (`if (!q_valMap.containsKey(key))`), it vivifies a new `HashSet` for that key, but it doesn't add `value` to it before returning. (And the returned value is the old value for that key, so it'll be null.) So you're going to be losing one of the Q-values for every term.

For multi-layered data structures like this, I usually special-case just the vivification of the intermediate structure, and then do the adding and return in a single code path. I think this would fix it. (I'm also going to call it `valSet` because it's a set and not a list. And there's no need to re-add the set to the map each time; it's a reference type and gets added the first time you encounter that key.)

```
public static HashSet<String> put_to_hash(String key, String value) 
{
    if (!q_valMap.containsKey(key)) {
        q_valMap.put(key, new HashSet<String>());
    } 
    HashSet<String> valSet = q_valMap.get(key);
    valSet.add(value);
    return valSet;
}
```

Also be aware that the `Set` you return is a reference to the live `Set` for that key, so you need to be careful about modifying it in callers, and if you're doing multithreading you're going to have concurrent access issues.

Or just use a Guava `Multimap` so you don't have to worry about writing the implementation yourself.

Comment: i got a `nullpointer exception` at the line ` valSet.add(value);`

Comment: Okay, that should take care of it.

Comment: Also, as a design consideration, I'd consider using the names with spaces as the keys, not "+" signs – the "+" is a URL encoding thing, so you might want to delay that substitution until constructing the actual URL to fetch.

Comment: hmm, so your saying the plus signs should be added to the data when i do the url call but the data should be stored without them?

Comment: Yes. The plus signs are a URL encoding mechanism. It should happen immediately before you concatenate them with the other bits of the URL string. Even inline like `"...site=en&page=" + variable_entity.replace(' ', '+') + "&submit=Search"`. But really, you need to URL-encode all special characters, not just spaces, so call a URL-encoding function instead of doing that single-character replacement.

Comment: that sounds great. I'd never even heard of a URL-encoding function before, but you're right I definetly need that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75997/discussion-between-andrew-janke-and-s-matthew-english).