# Map<String, HashSet<String>> to JSON, & Pretty Print

Tags: json, hashmap, jackson, data-conversion

I'm trying to make my dataset correspond to this example:

```
var family = [{
    "name" : "Jason",
    "age" : "24",
    "gender" : "male"
},
{
    "name" : "Kyle",
    "age" : "21",
    "gender" : "male"
}];
```

I have a `Map<String, HashSet<String>>` of Names and unique alpha-numeric values correponding to specific entities to which those names could refer, let's call these entry items "IDs".

So for instance, `Fyodor Mikhailovich Dostoyevsky` would perhaps be related to the ID `Q626`, because that's a very specific reference, there aren't many widely known figures with that name. Whereas, `Bush` might be attached to `G027`, `Q290`, and `Q118`, referencing perhaps the man, the beer, and the shrub, in no particular order.

It looks like this (the real one is much bigger):

```
[Rao=[Q7293658, , Q7293657, Q12953055, Q3531237, Q4178159, Q1138810, Q579515, Q3365064, Q7293664, Q1133815], Hani Durzy=[], Louise=[, Q1660645, Q130413, Q3215140, Q152779, Q233203, Q7871343, Q232402, Q82547, Q286488, Q156723, Q3263649, Q456386, Q233192, Q14714149, Q12125864, Q57669, Q168667, Q141410, Q166028], Reyna=[Q7573462, Q2892895, Q363257, Q151944, Q3740321, Q2857439, Q1453358, Q7319529, Q733716, Q16151941, Q7159448, Q5484172, Q6074271, Q1753185, Q7319532, Q5171205, Q3183869, Q1818527, Q251862, Q3840414, Q5271282, Q5606181]]
```

---

Using Jackson I tried like this:

```
Map<String, HashSet<String>>  map = q_valMap;
mapper.writeValue(new File("JSON_Output/user.json"), map);
```

But this seems wrong, as my output was all jumbled together, i.e.

```
{"Rao":["Q7293658","","Q7293657","Q12953055","Q3531237","Q4178159","Q1138810","Q579515","Q3365064","Q7293664","Q1133815"],"Hani Durzy":[""],"Louise":["","Q1660645","Q130413","Q3215140","Q152779","Q233203","Q7871343","Q232402","Q82547","Q286488","Q156723","Q3263649","Q456386","Q233192","Q14714149","Q12125864","Q57669","Q168667","Q141410","Q166028"],"Reyna":["Q7573462","Q2892895","Q363257","Q151944","Q3740321","Q2857439","Q1453358","Q7319529","Q733716","Q16151941","Q7159448","Q5484172","Q6074271","Q1753185","Q7319532","Q5171205","Q3183869","Q1818527","Q251862","Q3840414","Q5271282","Q5606181"]}
```

Do I just have to populate this JSON object iteratively?

---

Like the example up top, I think it should look something like this, though what follows is only a pseudocodish characterization, which is to say, not exactly this but something similar:

```
{
    key: "Rao"
    value:  ["Q7293658","","Q7293657","Q12953055","Q3531237","Q4178159","Q1138810","Q579515","Q3365064","Q7293664","Q1133815"]

    key: "Hani Durzy"
    value: [""]

    key: "Louise"
    value: ["","Q1660645","Q130413","Q3215140","Q152779","Q233203","Q7871343","Q232402","Q82547","Q286488","Q156723","Q3263649","Q456386","Q233192","Q14714149","Q12125864","Q57669","Q168667","Q141410","Q166028"]

    key: "Reyna"
    value: ["Q7573462","Q2892895","Q363257","Q151944","Q3740321","Q2857439","Q1453358","Q7319529","Q733716","Q16151941","Q7159448","Q5484172","Q6074271","Q1753185","Q7319532","Q5171205","Q3183869","Q1818527","Q251862","Q3840414","Q5271282","Q5606181"]
}
```

is that not right?

---

**UPDATE**

```
public class JsonMapFileExample 
{
    public static void map(Map<String, HashSet<String>> q_valMap ) 
    {

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();


        ArrayNode array = mapper.createArrayNode();
        for ( Entry entry: q_valMap.entrySet() ) 
        {
          ObjectNode node = mapper.createObjectNode()
              .put("name", entry.getKey())
              .put("ids", entry.getValue());
          array.add(node);
        }
        mapper.writeValue("/home/matthias/Workbench/SUTD/nytimes_corpus/wdtk-parent/wdtk-examples/JSON_Output/user.json", array);

    }
}


class MyEntity
{
    private String name;
    Set<String> value; // use names that you want in the result JSON

    //constructors
    public MyEntity() 
    {

    }
    public MyEntity(String name) 
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    //getters
    public String getName() 
    {
        return this.name;
    }
    public Set<String>  getValue() 
    {
        return this.value;
    }

    //setters
    public void setName(String name) 
    {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public void setValue(Set<String> value) 
    {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: try to use json_pp (cli tool) to format your json.

Comment: @iced thank you for checking this out. what do you think of the answer i just wrote?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could manually set the key names, something like:

```
ArrayNode array = mapper.createArrayNode();
for (Entry entry: yourMap.entries()) {
  ObjectNode node = mapper.createObjectNode()
      .put("name", entry.key())
      .putPOJO("ids", entry.value());
  array.add(node);
}
mapper.writeValue(file, array);
```

Alternatively, you could create a class for your data

```
class MyEntity {
  String name;
  Set<String> ids; // use names that you want in the JSON result
  // getters, setters if necessary
}
```

Transform your data map into a list of `MyEntity`, then use Jackson `ObjectMapper` to create JSON like `mapper.writeValue(file, listOfMyEntities)`, the output would be like

```
[
  {
    "name": "some name here",
    "ids": ["id1", "id2", ...]  
  }
  // more elements here
]
```

Comment: would the output of that look like what i just added on the bottom of the question? does this use jackson?

Comment: what do you mean by malformed

Comment: You would have 4 `key` and 4 `value` in one JSON object, which is not good

Comment: but under `Storing JSON Data in Arrays` in [this site](http://www.copterlabs.com/blog/json-what-it-is-how-it-works-how-to-use-it/), that's what I'm going for. but I don't know how to make it.

Comment: Please find my updates and see if it's what you're looking for

Comment: seems createArrayNode is undefined for `Map<String, HashSet<String>>`

Comment: under **UPDATE** I added what I've been doing. it doesn't like that `put` there's some error about I should cast it to a json node. 

I made getters and setters for that class, how could i make a list of those?

Comment: If you ever read the documentation or looked at the API popped up in your IDE, you will find how to add an object

Comment: do you have a reference to the documentation i need to look at? i've been trying to find it

Answer (score 0):

how about this:

```
        String name_list_file = "/home/matthias/Workbench/SUTD/nytimes_corpus/NYTimesCorpus/2005/01/02/test/people_test.txt";

        String single_name;

        try (   
                // read in the original file, list of names, w/e
                InputStream stream_for_name_list_file = new FileInputStream( name_list_file );
                InputStreamReader stream_reader = new InputStreamReader( stream_for_name_list_file , Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
                BufferedReader line_reader = new BufferedReader( stream_reader );
            ) 
        {
            while (( single_name = line_reader.readLine() ) != null) 
            {
                //replace this by a URL encoder
                //String associated_alias = single_name.replace(' ', '+');
                String associated_alias = URLEncoder.encode( single_name , "UTF-8");

                String platonic_key = single_name;
                System.out.println("now processing: " + platonic_key);

                Wikidata_Q_Reader.getQ( platonic_key, associated_alias );
            }
        }

        //print the struc
        Wikidata_Q_Reader.print_data();


    }
```