# How to parse JSON object into `Map<String, HashSet<String>>`

Tags: java, json

I'd like to parse this JSON object:

```
"{
  \"Rao\":[\"Q7293658\",\"\",\"Q7293657\",\"Q12953055\",\"Q3531237\",\"Q4178159\",\"Q1138810\",\"Q579515\",\"Q3365064\",\"Q7293664\",\"Q1133815\"],
  \"Hani Durzy\":[\"\"],
  \"Louise\":[\"\",\"Q1660645\",\"Q130413\",\"Q3215140\",\"Q152779\",\"Q233203\",\"Q7871343\",\"Q232402\",\"Q82547\",\"Q286488\",\"Q156723\",\"Q3263649\",\"Q456386\",\"Q233192\",\"Q14714149\",\"Q12125864\",\"Q57669\",\"Q168667\",\"Q141410\",\"Q166028\"],
  \"Reyna\":[\"Q7573462\",\"Q2892895\",\"Q363257\",\"Q151944\",\"Q3740321\",\"Q2857439\",\"Q1453358\",\"Q7319529\",\"Q733716\",\"Q16151941\",\"Q7159448\",\"Q5484172\",\"Q6074271\",\"Q1753185\",\"Q7319532\",\"Q5171205\",\"Q3183869\",\"Q1818527\",\"Q251862\",\"Q3840414\",\"Q5271282\",\"Q5606181\"]
}"
```

and with that data generate a `Map<String, HashSet<String>>`.

Essentially I want to reverse [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29838841/mapstring-hashsetstring-to-json-pretty-print) procedure.

All the code for this project can be found [on my github page here](https://github.com/h1395010/database_builder/tree/master/src/main/java/Q), it's quite short.

---

**update**

```
        File f = new File("/home/matthias/Workbench/SUTD/nytimes_corpus/wdtk-parent/wdtk-examples/JSON_Output/user.json");

        String jsonTxt = null;

        if (f.exists())
        {
            InputStream is = new FileInputStream("/home/matthias/Workbench/SUTD/nytimes_corpus/wdtk-parent/wdtk-examples/JSON_Output/user.json");
            jsonTxt = IOUtils.toString(is);


        }
        //System.out.println(jsonTxt);


        Gson gson=new Gson(); 


        Map<String, HashSet<String>> map = new HashMap<String, HashSet<String>>();
        map=(Map<String, HashSet<String>>) gson.fromJson(jsonTxt, map.getClass());

        //// \\ // ! PRINT IT ! // \\ // \\ // \\ // \\ // \\ // \\
       for (Map.Entry<String, HashSet<String>> entry : map.entrySet()) 
       {
           System.out.println(entry.getKey()+" : " + Arrays.deepToString(map.entrySet().toArray()) );
       }
```

Comment: show us you java code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using [`Gson`](https://github.com/google/gson)

```
Gson gson = new Gson(); 
String json = "<YOUR_JSON_STRING_HERE>";
Map<String, HashSet<String>> map = new HashMap<String, HashSet<String>>();
map = (Map<String, HashSet<String>>) gson.fromJson(json, map.getClass());
```

---

Update:

Use `TypeToken`

```
Type type = new TypeToken<Map<String, HashSet<String>>>(){}.getType();
map = (Map<String, HashSet<String>>) gson.fromJson(json, type);
```

---

Or you could parse it...

- Create an object of [`JSONObject`](http://www.json.org/java/index.html)
- Create an object of `HashMap`
- Iterate over `jsonObj.keys()` and for every `key` get `value` like
  `jsonObj.getString(key)`.
- Put it in the `map` like `map.put(key, value)`.

Comment: what is a json string? can I just read in the file with bufferedreader and that will make a json string? I've never done this before please forgive me

Comment: @S.Matthew_English Yes.

Comment: i tried to do as you said but i got a strange error, i posted what i did to to original question

Comment: `Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 2`

Comment: maybe something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9598707/gson-throwing-expected-begin-object-but-was-begin-array)?

Comment: Well yes, I guess this calls for a separate discussion in another thread. All the best though :-)

Comment: what is `Type` my IDE offers me about 20 things to import for that but I can't tell which is the one? is it something about `gson`?

Comment: @S.Matthew_English Yes it's from gson http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/tags/1.1/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/reflect/TypeToken.html

Comment: maybe it's becasue the json object has `"` around it?